# Do the heroes I use for Tap Battles matter?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

With the most recent update, Fire Emblem Heroes now has "Tap Battles," which is essentially Tap Tap Revenge, but with Fire Emblem music as the songs and enemies as the notes.

Your active team shows up on the four lines, so I'm curious if who is on this team makes any sort of difference. Aside from the voices being different when you tap on the heroes' rows, is there any difference in gameplay when I choose different heroes for this game mode?

Comment: I was wondering this myself.. there doesn't seem to be any bonus or difference as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of patch 2.5, the 4 heroes you bring in now gain hero merit, that is the only reason to bring in certain heroes :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't matter which characters you use, since you don't get any experience from the event.